# Casting a custom TextView crashes my app

Tags: android, textview

I ve got a custom TextView Class witch extend TextView:

```
public class MessagingTextView extends TextView {
public MessagingTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public void make(String body, Boolean sent){
    this.setText(body);
    if (sent){
        this.setPadding(10, 10, 25, 10);
        this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sent_bubble);

    }
    else{
        this.setPadding(25, 10, 10, 10);
        this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sent_bubble);
    }
}
```

}

In my activity (in a custom adapter) I instantiate this class by the following code:

```
MessagingTextView body = (MessagingTextView)item.findViewById(R.id.s4_msg_body);
body.make(currentMsg.getBody(), currentMsg.getSent());
```

When I run that code my app crashes and the log shows a Cast Exception.
Could you tell how can I solve that?
Thanks in advance!

Here is the Xml s4_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/s4_msg_body"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/s4_msg_date"
    android:text="Message body"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/s4_msg_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Message date"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @XOOLOOO I added the XMl item file, hope it will help.

Comment: you should add your own namespaced component into the xml file <yourPackageName.YourTextView>

Comment: I did so, the log shows an inflate exception

Comment: can you update the problem and xml with what you have ? also why in tv `android:id="@+id/s4_msg_body"` there is `android:layout_below="@+id/s4_msg_date"` when `android:id="@+id/s4_msg_date"` is after that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML you are declaring a `TextView`. You can't just cast that to an arbitrary subclass, in this case your `MessagingTextView`. If you want it to be a subclass then you'll have to declare it as such.

Something like:

```
<com.some.package.name.MessagingTextView
    android:id="@+id/s4_msg_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Message date"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```